# What to do when Cake doesn't say what is wrong?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

What to do when model does not save or return any type of error?

```
$data = array(
    'Model' => array(
        'field1' => 'value1',
        'field2' => 'value2',
    )
);

try {
    // Forget to add this
    $this->Model->set($data);

    if (!$this->Model->validates()) { // Returns true
        throw new GenericErrorException("Can't validate");
    }

    $this->Model->create();
    if (!$this->Model->save($data)) { // Returns false
        debug($this->Model->invalidFields()); // Empty array
        debug($this->Model->getDatasource()->getLog()); // Returns array without INSERT/UPDATE

        throw new GenericErrorException("Can't save");
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // LOG ERROR
}
```

Have anything I can do to verify what is happening wrong?

Comment: Having `if (!$this->Model->validates()) {` before you've set any data on the model doesn't make sense. Do you have a `beforeSave` callback that is returning false and stopping the save operation? Any behaviors? What about the values of `$this->Model->validationErrors;`

Comment: You are not using CakePHP correctly, thus it can't tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @tigrang I forgot to add the code, but have setted data before validate, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what you’re doing. You should be saving data as the result of a `POST` or `PUT` request:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Model->save($this->request->data)) {
            // model saved; set flash message and redirect
        }
        else {
            // save failed; errors in $this->Model->validationErrors
        }
    }
}
```

If you follow CakePHP’s conventions, you’ll have a smoother experience. Calling `save()` on your model will also attempt to validate your data before saving too, so there’s no need to manually validate.

Comment: Hey, `$data` represents posted data. I do validation before save because I have some logics besides throw the exception.

Comment: Where is this logic? In your model? Can you show this logic? As this might help us better understand the problem.

Comment: This logic is irrelavant because the `validates()` returns true, so, all logic is ignored.

Comment: Well it would help if that’s where the problem’s occurring. Thus without, we can’t help. Only thing I can suggest is check your error log, which you should have already done.

Answer (score 0):

adding `$this->Model->validationErrors;` always do the tricks.